# FBSDKShareDialog doesn't display app name in Facebook for sharing FBSDKSharePhoto but it displays app name for FBSDKShareLinkContent

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-share, fbsdksharekit

I tried to post photo from my app to Facebook using FBSDKShareDialog. While doing so, sharing of link via FBSDKSharePhoto won't display my app name whereas FBSDKShareLinkContent does displays my app name.

Comment: Ok? Do you have a question?

Comment: Yeah,,,so what is wrong with it. App name is displayed while using FBSDKShareLinkContent  but not using FBSDKSharePhoto?